# Gap between list item and nested sub-menu list causes loss of the hover state

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

I am trying to create a drop down menu that is pure css3, using the pseudoelements `:before` and `:after` to create a styled tooltip arrow that displays on top of the nested `li`'s that "drop down" when you hover over the top level `li`.

My problem is that the menu disappears as soon as my mouse leaves the `li` that I am hovered over. It will not allow me to move my mouse down and hover over the nested `li`'s and I think this is because I have a gap between the nested `li`'s and the top level `li`'s, this gap being used for the styled pseudoelement tool-tip arrow.

I have an example of what I am doing in this jfiddle, it will give you better idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/46andtool/dS6G7/1/

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <ul id="ddmenu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Donations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Volunteering</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Housing</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    <li><a href="#">International</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">China</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Japan</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Australia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">South America</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
#ddmenu {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 2px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #8aa8bd;
}

#ddmenu li { display: block; position: relative; float: left; font-size: 1.45em; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff; border-right: 1px solid #dae0e5; }

#ddmenu li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 12px;
  line-height: 78px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FF0000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
#ddmenu li:hover > a { color: #565051; background: #C0C0C0; 



}


#ddmenu li:hover ul {

    display:  block;

}


#ddmenu li a:hover ul {

    display: block;
}

#ddmenu ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 88px;
  width: 130px;
  background: #fff;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px 0;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


#ddmenu ul:after:hover ul {
    display: block;

}


#ddmenu ul:before:hover ul {

    display: block;

}
/* tooltip arrow */
#ddmenu ul:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 8px;
  border-width: 1px 8px 8px 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff transparent; 

}


#ddmenu ul:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 4px;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;  
}

#ddmenu ul li { 
  display: block; 
  width: 100%; 
  font-size: 0.9em; 
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
}

#ddmenu ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 7px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
#ddmenu ul li a:hover {


  background: #C0C0C0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You HAVE to fill the gap.

Add transparent pseudo elements as childs of the first level's li tags for example :

```
#ddmenu li:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 12px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

[Here is the updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dS6G7/2/)

Answer (score 0):

> I think this is because I have a gap between the nested li's and the top level li's

Between the *`UL`* nested into the top-level `LI`, to be more precise, but yes, that is of course the problem. So to fix it, you will have to close that gap.

One simple way of doing that in this specific case could be to just give the top-level `LI` a `border-bottom:10px solid transparent`. That way, your `LI` stretch further down until where the absolutely positioned `UL` start, so there is no *gap* any more – and since the border is transparent, there is no *visual* effect ;-)

http://jsfiddle.net/dS6G7/3/

---

And that selector

```
#ddmenu li a:hover ul { … }
```

doesn’t make any sense btw., because you don’t have your `UL` nested into those `A` elements.

Comment: ah okay thanks for explaining this to me, I thought that might be a fix at first because my reasoning was that the nested li's disappear because I need to give them a hover pseudoclass as well, not realizing this was already taken care of by  `#ddmenu li:hover ul { display:  block; } ` and my real problem was that little pseudoelement gap :)